# NightmareJS code working but missing an element

Tags: automated-testing, nightmarejs

I have this [NightmareJS](http://www.nightmarejs.org/) code for testing.

I want to click Location Menu (which works fine) and clicking on any of the location menu sub menus works fine.. but for feature menu I am unable to get to say Traffic Cameras and Waze. Any suggestions?

This part is not working:

```
.click('i[title="toggleWaze"]')
.screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1_featureWaze.png')
```

The website under test can be found here: https://smartway.tn.gov/traffic/

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

var bandcamp = new Nightmare()
    .viewport(1000, 1000)
    .useragent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36")
    .goto('https://dev.tdot.tn.gov/smartway/traffic/')
    .wait(5000)
    .screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1.png')
    .click('button[title="Feature Menu"]')
    .wait(5000)
    .screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1_feature.png'

    .click('i[title="toggleWaze"]')
    .screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1_featureWaze.png')

    .click('a[title="Chattanooga"]')
    .wait(3000)
    .screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1_location1.png')

        .run(function (err, nightmare) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('Done!');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after having a more thorough understanding of elements from my colleague.  It is a button.  change that to this....click('button[data-qa-hook="toggleWaze"]')

Answer (score 0):

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

var nightmare = Nightmare({show: true})
    .viewport(1000, 1000)
    .useragent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36")
    .goto('https://smartway.tn.gov/traffic/')
    .wait(5000)
    .screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1.png')

    .click('button[title="Feature Menu"]')
    .wait('button[data-qa-hook="toggleWaze"]')
    .screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1_feature.png')

    .click('button[data-qa-hook="toggleWaze"]')
    .wait(3000)
    .screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1_featureWaze.png')

    .wait('button[data-qa-hook="LocationMenu"]')
    .click('button[data-qa-hook="LocationMenu"]')

    .wait('a[title="Chattanooga"]')
    .click('a[title="Chattanooga"]')

    .wait(3000)
    .screenshot('screenshots/n/smartway1_location1.png')

    .run(function (err, nightmare) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('Done!');
    });
```